# t-sql replacing double quotes

Tags: t-sql, replace, quotes

I have a t-sql statement like `Replace(field,'\''','\"')` because i have two different results 
''field1'' and "field2" but what if i consider those two different results the same and want to group them. I choose to group those two by replacing the first double quotes with the second style but although replaced they are not interpreted as the same type of quote.

What I am missing here??

Edited: I am trying to group data where text is the same but quotes differ, user is entering two single quotes ''hello'' and one double quote "hello", if I have this two rows I am trying to display them as one as "hello", so by executing the above statement I think I should be able to do this, but it isn't working properly even without slashes.

Comment: could you elaborate a little? I'm at a complete loss for what you are asking and what your data looks like....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look at this code:

```
DECLARE @X  varchar(20)
SET @X='''''Hello"'

PRINT @X
PRINT REPLACE(@X,'''''','"')
PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@X,'''''',''''),'"','''')
```

here is the output:

```
''Hello"
"Hello"
'Hello'
```

SQL Server does not escape quotes with slashes, a single quote is escaped with another single quote.  This will print one single qoute:

```
print ''''
```

this will print two single quotes:

```
print ''''''
```

Comment: Thx!  I used your solution to replace double double-quotes with two single quotes and double-quotes with single-quote: `replace(replace(left(itemf.[t_dsca],30) ,'""', ''''''),'"', '')`